# Gps gap problem in fused location provider

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am developing a GPS monitoring application but I am having problems receiving the GPS updates when the application is running on background.
During the route the GPS stops updating and only starts running again after some time.

I am using the FusedLocationProviderClient api with the following parameters:

```
return new LocationRequest()
.SetInterval( 2000 )
.SetFastestInterval( 500 )
.SetSmallestDisplacement(1)
.SetPriority( LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy );
```

Im using a hybrid service to track the gps updates.
When i start the application i bound using this:

```
public PortalCorridaServiceConnection BindService() {

    if( ServiceConnection == null ) {

        ServiceConnection = new PortalCorridaServiceConnection( Activity );
Intent intentService = new Intent( Activity, typeof( PortalCorridaService ) );
         Activity.BindService( intentService, ServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate );

    }

    return ServiceConnection;

}
```

And when the "start track button" is pressed i start my service as foreground like this

```
public void StartForegroundService() {

    MakeToast( "Servico iniciado em foreground" );

    Intent intent = new Intent( Activity, typeof( Engine.PortalCorridaService ) );

    if( Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O ) {
        Activity.StartForegroundService( intent );
    } else {
        Activity.StartService( intent );
    }

}
```

```
public void RegisterForegroundService() {

    // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements:
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, "PORTALCORRIDA" )
        .SetContentTitle( "Portal da Corrida" )
        .SetContentText( "Estamos monitorando sua corrida" )
        .SetSmallIcon( Resource.Drawable.ic_media_play_light );

    // Build the notification:
    MainNotification = builder.Build();

    // Get the notification manager:
    NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService( Context.NotificationService ) as NotificationManager;

    // Publish the notification:
    //const int notificationId = 0;
    //notificationManager.Notify( notificationId, notification );

    // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
    StartForeground( SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, MainNotification );

}
```

And then i call

```
fusedLocationProviderClient.RequestLocationUpdatesAsync( CreateLocationRequest(), locationCallback );
```

[GPS Gap error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tCAc.jpg)
the straight line between the arrows is the gap.

I also tried the app in another smartphone with same results

Is there anything I can do to improve the GPS updates ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantees that you'll always have GPS reception.

Not having GPS can be caused by several factors, like not having a proper view to several satellites, but it can also be because your phone tries to save battery, and your OS decides to disable GPS. The exact rules of when GPS gets disabled are not very well documented for both iOS and Android, but it makes sense that background services or apps that don't have the focus tend to get GPS to be disabled sooner.

If (for whatever reason) there is no GPS, your phone can fall back to alternative methods, like GSM cell tower triangulation, or know WiFi locations if they are in view. That's much more battery-friendly.

But note that if your location is determined by GSM towers, your accuracy drops a lot, and if it's nearby WiFi routers that are used, the location manager keeps returning a location every second, but it'll be the same coordinates every time, something changes (e.g. GPS is back, or a new WiFi router is found).

In such cases you'll also see what you're experiencing.

You could also experience the OS stalling your application or service for other reasons of course..

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know that, the akward is when i start tracking by my app and by another application like run keeper, etc, the other app track without the gaps

Comment: @BrunoCerquiare: the most likely cause is that your app is not in the foreground, and your OS decides that this is a waste of battery. There are several ways to work around that. You could for example create a "foreground service" to collect GPS data. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground.